# Styling HTML buttons in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In my HTML I have the following:

```
<a href="http://kb.domain.com/" class="button1">Knowledge Base</a>
<br />
```

In my CSS I have the following classes:

```
.button1 {
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    Color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

The link color is blue, I want to make the link black with white background. I want to change this on hover by making the background black and the link color white.
I can't make it by using the following CSS class:

```
.button1 a:hover {
    background: #393939;
    Color: #ffffff;
}
```

Do I have to change my HTML to be:

```
  <button class="button1" id="save">Sample button</button>
```

Please advice. I appreciate your support

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
a.button1:hover {
    background: #393939;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

.button1 is already your link. What you did is tell to look for a link inside .button1

EDIT: also the name for the attributes is lower case

Answer (score 1):

Is that something like that http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNMLar ?

```
a.button1:hover {
    background: #000;
    Color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```